# Firebase does not save data in database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firewall

Good morning, could someone tell me what are the ports that realtime database usese? I believe it is not the same as FCM or am I mistaken?

The port 80 and 443 are released, but when I go to send something to the database it does not send if I change to a network where everything is released it sends someone would have any idea what it can be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone wants to release the firebase in the firewall, you have to apply a rule to the following ips:

74.125.0.0/16 
35.192.0.0/12

Comment: If that was what resolved your problem, you should mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Realtime Database communicates between the client and server over HTTPS, which uses port 443.

When available it uses Web Sockets for the communications, but those too go over port 443.

Comment: Port 80 and 443 are released, but when I'm going to send something to the database it does not send if I move to a network where everything is released it sends would you have any idea what it might be?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of asking about what you think is the problem/solution, update your question describe the actual problem you're observing.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot network connections remotely, so the best I can do is point you to some tools. First of these is https://www.firebase.com/test.html, which tries to connect in a way similar to actual clients and show debug logging. If that doesn't help, enable debug logging on your platform (since you didn't specify what platform you run on, just search for "firebase enable debug logging <your_platform>") and check the debug output of your app for hints.